# PHP function with return code and return message for information purposes

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

This php code is called through ajax from javascript and should return a numeric code and a message.  I can return an array from the PHP script but when I read the ajax response that response contains more than the returned array, it has the other echoed statements.  Is there a way to send information from the Php that is only the return array?  I want only the json object `{"return_code":0,"return_msg":"Login successful."}`.

This is the information returned through ajax to the javascript with `alert(login_info);`.

> ```
> Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
> ```
>
> date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
>   methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for
>   'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/Pagelinks_Dev/login_user.php on line 60
>       {"return_code":0,"return_msg":"Login successful."}

This is the ajax call.

```
var message = $.ajax({
    url: "login_user.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { username_email: username_email, upass: user_passwd },
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function (login_info) {
        if (login_info != '') 
        {
          alert(login_info);
        }
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert ("status "+status+" error "+error+"responseText "+request.responseText);
    },
}).responseText;
```

PHP script

```
<?php include("dbconnect.php"); ?>

<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();

function login_user( $username_email, $password_text ) {
    global $dbco;

    $password = md5($password_text);
    $privPost = 1; // 3: max.
    $privSedit = 0;

    $messages = array( 'log_no_un_em' => 'Enter username or email.',
            'log_no_pw' => 'Enter password.',
            'log_un_em_pw_incorrect' => 'Incorrect login info.',
            'log_success' => 'Login successful.'
    );

    $return = array();

    $l_un_em = isset($username_email) ? $username_email : '';
    $l_pword = isset($password_text) ? $password_text : '';

    if (!$l_un_em) {
        /* echo $messages['log_no_un_em'];
        return; */
        $return['return_code'] = -1;
        $return['return_msg'] = $messages['log_no_un_em'];
        echo json_encode($return);
    }
    if (!$l_pword) {
        /* echo $messages['log_no_pw'];
        return; */
        $return['return_code'] = -1;
        $return['return_msg'] = $messages['log_no_pw'];
        echo json_encode($return);
    }

    mysql_select_db("luxcal", $dbco);

    while (true) {
        $md5_pw = md5($password_text);
        $r_getuser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (user_name = BINARY '".mysql_real_escape_string($l_un_em)."' OR email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($l_un_em)."') AND (password = '$md5_pw' OR temp_password = '$md5_pw') AND status >= 0");
        if (mysql_num_rows($r_getuser) == 0) {
            /* echo $messages['log_un_em_pw_incorrect'];
            return; */
            $return['return_code'] = -1;
            $return['return_msg'] = $messages['log_un_em_pw_incorrect'];
            echo json_encode($return);
        }
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r_getuser);
        /* if ($row['privs'] < 1) { echo $messages['log_no_privs']; break; } */
        if ($row['temp_password'] == $md5_pw) { //new password
            mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password = '".$md5_pw."', temp_password = NULL WHERE user_id = '{$row['user_id']}'");
        }
        $today = date('Y-m-d');
        if ($row['login_0'][0] == '9') { //first login
            mysql_query("UPDATE users SET login_0 = '".$today."', login_1 = '".$today."', login_cnt = 1 WHERE user_id = '{$row['user_id']}'");
        } else {
            mysql_query("UPDATE users SET login_1 = '".$today."', login_cnt = login_cnt+1 WHERE user_id = '{$row['user_id']}'");
        }
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['unm'] = stripslashes($row['user_name']);
        $_SESSION['uml'] = stripslashes($row['email']);
        $_SESSION['cL'] = $row['language'];
        /* echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=livemass_CENTER34.php">'; */ //default page
        break;
    }

    $return['return_code'] = 0;
    $return['return_msg'] = $messages['log_success'];

    echo json_encode($return);
    /* return; */
}

echo login_user(trim($_REQUEST['username_email']), trim($_REQUEST['upass']));

?>
```

Comment: `async: false` - **BAD**. Especially for something simple such as logging in using synchronous requests is completely unnecessary and wrong.

Comment: I would read the warning before posting on SO. It clearly says to use [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to set the timezone because it thinks you shouldn't rely on its default. If you didn't understand the warning, try Googling part of it. Chances are you aren't the first to have experienced it.

Comment: I can't think of a way to provide a better answer than the one already provided in the PHP warning you've posted in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return json, you can't have any other text outputted with the json string. Change `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to `ini_set('display_errors', 0);`

Comment: That's true.  I'd rather show the errors and still have a way of retrieving the json object.  But, I am able to separate the json object by turning off the errors

Comment: True, but you're not hiding *that* warning, you're hiding *all* notices, warnings and errors. Either way, a warning is usually the system trying to *help* you, not throwing obstacles in your way for the fun of it.

Comment: @DCoder Yes, but the warnings and errors should still show in the server log. OP was asking why their json didn't work, and the answer is because there's other text coming along with the json string. I guess the general point of my answer was to demonstrate that you can't return a json string with a bunch of other junk and expect the result to be parseable. I still fully recommend looking into / fixing that warning (and other errors).

Answer (score 2):

In your php file use

```
 date_default_timezone_set('your time zone');
```

to tell php what your timezone is. For more details see [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Comment: With some more information (What can be placed within the quotes?), I'd say this answer could be better than the accepted one.

Comment: This will be changed depending upon your requirement...if your site  is related to any specific country or area...for example for LA in US  it would be.... date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

Comment: Perhaps a link to the list of all of the valid timezones you can use would be helpful to the OP...

Comment: Yes of course... I had given it above with my answer. Here it again     http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php  Click on your Continent and you will have the list.